# Are there any languages which don't have Diphthongs at all?

Tags: diphthongs

For example my native language, Georgian has no Diphthongs, Adjacent vowels do occur but they are heterosyllabic ([source](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/A7DCF9606BA856FCA5CC25918ADB37EF/S0025100306002659a.pdf/standard_georgian.pdf))

are there any other languages which don't have any Diphthongs and adjacent vowels remain heterosyllabic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is generally the case in Bantu languages (there are hundreds) that vowel-vowel sequences other than same-vowel (i.e. long vowel) are two syllables. Likewise Tigrinya, Amharic and Tigre, as well as Arabic varieties (there are vowel+glide sequences which may be treated by some as "diphthongs"). This raises the question of what distinguishes diphthongs from vowel-glide sequences. The standard answer is that a diphthong in VV and a vowel+glide is VC, which implies having a diagnostic for C versus V. North Saami has both diphthongs and vowel-glide sequences, which act very differently in the phonology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most dialects of Yi under the Sino-Tibetan languages don't have diphthongs. Like Chinese, Yi characters are monosyllabic. Adjacent vowels, which appear when the second character in a word doesn't have an onset, remain heterosyllabic.

The Yi language is quite interesting in that its rhyme is very simple, where a glide or a coda, either with a vowel or a constant, is impossible. Phonologically, all syllables in the language are open and only has one short vowel monophone (including syllabic m and m̥, ɿ, ʅ, which are also generally considered as "vowels" in the Sino-Tibetan phonology).

There does exist, however, several dialects of Yi which have a vocalic (thus diphthongs) or a constant coda, notably some in Yunnan have vocalic or nasal coda, while Bisu Yi in Thailand could have unreleased -p, -t, -k coda.